# Calculation of contour's x,y-axis length

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv

Good day everybody.

I am still working with [the same old program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971093/better-algorithm-for-edge-filter-in-video-programming) and so far I managed to find the area and the coordinate of the biggest contour based on calculation of the contour's moments.

```
double m_00 = cvGetSpatialMoment( &moments, 0, 0 ); //The area
double m_10 = cvGetSpatialMoment( &moments, 1, 0 );
double m_01 = cvGetSpatialMoment( &moments, 0, 1 );
float gravityX = (m_10 / m_00);     //center of x-axis              
float gravityY = (m_01 / m_00);     //center of y-axis
```

...and what I get is this:

[image: The screenshot]

...which is working nicely. But now I want to get the length of x-axis and y-axis of the contour/object, which is something like this:

[image: What I need]

The question is **is there any function that can calculate the x-axis and y-axis length of the contour?** If so, can anyone kindly give me some clue how to do it?

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

P/S: [The program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971093/better-algorithm-for-edge-filter-in-video-programming) I linked above is the old one so it has some error in it.

Comment: have you seen this?does it help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971162/i-have-prob-with-this-coding-related-to-find-the-contours

Comment: Seems pretty straightfoward... just iterate over the entire image and note the minimum and maximum x and y values of the pixels labelled as being on the contour. How was your red-outlined image generated?

Comment: @Rook:I use cvDrawContours for the red-outline.

Comment: @joey:I already tried cvArcLength like in the link you gave but the problem is it can only find x-axis length but not Y-axis. BTW thanks for you suggestion

Comment: Then you don't even need to inspect the image; you just traver the `CvSeq` that you pass in to draw contours and inspect the x,y values of each point in that sequence, right?

Answer (score 0):

After I spend almost a day went around googling for the answer, I finally found an alternative way to get the width and the height of the object, which is by using 
[cvBoundingRect](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) function. Basically it will make an upright bounding rectangle around the contour, so I just need to retrieve the width and the height of the box to get what I want.

The code:

```
    Rect rect= cvBoundingRect(contour,0);
    double pt1, pt2;
    pt1 =rect.width;      //width
    pt2 =rect.height;     //heigth
```

BTW thanks for all your help. Cheers.